# gitinfo/gitinfo2: how to work around errors with underscores in git tags/branches?

Tags: gitinfo, underscore

Using the [`gitinfo2`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/gitinfo2) package, I've run into errors which appear to originate from git tags or branch names that contain underscores. These would need to be escaped for LaTeX, `gitinfo2` commands such as `\gitReferences` can be used.
My question is how best to work around these errors. Should I modify the `post-*` hooks to replace all `_` characters with `\_`? I've also tried to apply one of the hacks described [here](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-underscore) and [here](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-activechars), without success.

Or would it be better to request an upstream fix from the package author ([Brent.Longborough](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/344/brent-longborough))?

Btw, this seems to also affect the obsolete `gitinfo` package, but presumably development on that has shifted to the new package.

Comment: Did you get this to work?
It seems like something that should be fixed upstream if possible.

Comment: @NathanMusoke Since we don't have an MWE or any follow-up from the OP, this looks unanswerable. (We don't know that this wasn't a bug which has now been fixed, even.)